# Highlight image portion thats being clicked

Tags: java, android, eclipse, image, tablet

[image: verses of book]

I have images of the Holy Quran. Each image has different verses (one complete sentence.) Some verses are in one line, some are in 2 and some are in 3 lines. Please view the attached image. If user clicks on verse 4, then this complete verse should be highlighted (draw some overlay over the verse with opacity low, so it displays as if the verse is highlighted.)

1. How should i do this?
2. How should i get which verse is selected. As android has different devices screen, and different resolution. Some big som small etc etc.

Is this possible ?

Note: We have images, not text.

Comment: You could maybe make the ImageViews clickable if you just can add onClickListener to each of them. Additionally, one way to achieve color change would be using clickable background image for each ImageView. If your images are not translucent I think you can add color states for ``android:tint``. Just a few thoughts.

Comment: How can this be achieved for multiple line verse. For example verse 4 in the above attached image.

Comment: Is the situation such that you have a verse consisting of two ImageViews? And if the user clicks on that particular verse, both ImageViews should be in pressed state? If this is the case you can share the OnClickObserver among with both ImageViews. And use ``setPressed`` method for the view which was not clicked. Haven't tried this myself though but am assuming this way you got to alter the other view's state.

Comment: But if i place the whole page as an image, then it helps in curl page effect. 
If i separate them and develop layouts for each image(verse by verse), then can the curl page effect be achieved with layouts ? i suppose curl page effect is for images only.

Comment: Ahhh. In that case I would suggest following: create a layout which consists of separate verse images instead. For page curl you can grab a "screenshot" of the layout and use it as Bitmap it requires. This way it would be more easy to handle the clicks and other layout functionality you might be after.

Comment: Thanks Harism for your help. Will try out this. Your support is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In that case I would suggest following: create a layout which consists of separate verse images and use image selector for hilight the images.